# Visual Studio Addin - Cant Create Child Menu Items

Tags: visual-studio-2008, menu, add-in

i am trying to create a basic menu structure for a visual studio 2008 addin. So far i can create the first top-level menu which in my example below i have called TOPMENU. I am struggling to figure out how to add child items to TOPMENU. I have tried a variety of ways and cant figure it out. Can someone help me finish off the code below? I am currently getting an invalid cast exception when i try to create object "a2" below.

```
void IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
{
 _ApplicationObject = (DTE2)application;
 _AddInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

 if (connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup)
 {
  object[] contextGUIDS = new object[] { };
  Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_ApplicationObject.Commands;
  CommandBar cbMainMenu = ((CommandBars)_ApplicationObject.CommandBars)["MenuBar"];

  try
  {
   // ROOT MENU
   Command cmdProjectManagement = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_AddInInstance, "TOPMENU", "TOPMENU", "",
    true, null, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported + (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled,
    (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStyleText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);

   if (cmdProjectManagement != null)
    cmdProjectManagement.AddControl(cbMainMenu, cbMainMenu.Controls.Count);

   // SUB ITEM
   Command cmdCompiledAssemblies = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_AddInInstance, "TOPMENU_CompiledAssemblies", "Compiled Assemblies", String.Empty,
    true, null, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported + (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled,
    (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStyleText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);

   CommandBarControl a1 = cbMainMenu.Controls["TOPMENU"];
   CommandBarPopup a2 = (CommandBarPopup)a1;

   if (cmdCompiledAssemblies != null)
    cmdCompiledAssemblies.AddControl(a2.CommandBar, 1);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: How did you create several submenus and separator line below TopMenu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full documentation on how to create all sorts of menu's and toolbar's here..

http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/mz2005003.aspx